# How do I get the same result of consul kv get -recurse with consul http api?

Tags: consul, consul-kv

I want to retrieve all saved keys and values of consul servers using its http api. Or at least how to get all saved keys using http api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [python-consul](https://python-consul.readthedocs.io/) library. Here's the example

```
import consul
consul_server = consul.Consul(host='127.0.0.1', port=8500)
consul_kv = consul_server.kv.get(key='', recurse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to retrieve the value for particular key.

`curl \ <your consul url>/v1/kv/<yourkey>`

I haven't used curl directly much but  [libraries](https://www.consul.io/api/libraries-and-sdks.html)  which gives more flexibility to use consul api. I have used [diplomat](https://github.com/WeAreFarmGeek/diplomat) in this which is a very powerful and yet very simple to use, its written in ruby. For getting all key value pairs recursively I can use get method

```
Diplomat::Kv.get('/', recurse: true)
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can list all the values using `curl` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a cli to list all the keys and values and export options also
https://github.com/amjad489/goconsul